# ARB test in subscription and webhook notification case

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-arb, authorize.net-webhooks

Created the subscription using ARB subscription and recurring events are handled by  the webhook notification. How can I test the events are working as the interval can given by 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

From a webhook perspective a subscription payment is no different then a regular payment with the only difference being the webhook will include the subscription ID in it. So if you can test  and handle a regular payment webhook, you can handle a subscription payment webhook.

Comment: How can I test webhook events after subscription creation

Comment: John where did you find this information ? It appears to not be documented.